# data context save changes not working in C# entity framwork

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2016

I am trying to execute below query

```cs
using (var dbcontext = new EVEntities())
{
    var data_header = dbcontext.Cl.Where(x => x.PKey == 
        header_key).FirstOrDefault();
    if (data_header != null)
    {
        data_header.EstimatedCost = Math.Round(estimated_cost,2);
        data_header.ClaimedCost = Math.Round(claimed_cost,2);
        dbcontext.Entry<Cl>(data_header).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        dbcontext.SaveChanges();
        Writelog("Updated");
    }
}
```

Here **Writelog** write in a text file and it is working always. But the field in Cl is not getting updated. In between the data is getting updated also.

**Connection String**

```
<connectionStrings><add name="EVEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/xxx_Entity_Model.csdl|res://*/xxx_Entity_Model.ssdl|res://*/xxx_Entity_Model.msl; provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=xxxxxx;initial catalog=xxxxx;persist security info=True;user id=xx;password=xxxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/></connectionStrings>
```

**Edit1**

tried raw update also

```
dbcontext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"UPDATE dbo.Claims 
SET EstimatedCost = @e_cost, ClaimedCost = @c_cost WHERE Pkey =
 @p_key",
new SqlParameter("e_cost", Math.Round(estimated_cost, 2)),
new SqlParameter("c_cost", Math.Round(claimed_cost, 2)),
new SqlParameter("p_key", claim_header_key));
```

same outcome. It get updated in between. No error.

Comment: Show us your connection string.

Comment: @John added connection string

Comment: Thanks but, unfortunately, that doesn't help the way I hoped it might. The issue is not what I thought it might be.

Comment: What happens if you add a new entity in that same code block? Do you see the new entity but not the modified one or do you see neither? is that explicitly setting of the entity state an attempt to deal with the issue or did you do that from the outset?

Comment: Are you using `AsNoTracking()` when creating that DbContext? `SaveChanges` works and saves all changes to the objects tracked by the DbContext. There's no need to change the object's state explicitly.

Comment: @John new entries will created. Here in update also in between the update is happening too..no error on try catch..tried that also. and everytime the write log work. so no error.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos will see AsNoTracking()

Comment: `dbcontext.Entry<Cl>(data_header).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;` - remove this line.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov tried without the same...no difference.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give us enough information to give you the solution. Therefore I give you a method to debug the problem.

- Does the DbContext think that anything must be saved?
- What SQL is sent to the database?

When you call SaveChanges, DbContext checks its [ChangeTracker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext.changetracker?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) to see if anything must be updated. Consider to write some Debug code to detect whether there are changes.

Insert just before SaveChanges:

```
bool changesDetected = dbContext.ChangeTracker.HasChanges;
```

It might be that you need to call `DetectChanges()` first. I'm not sure.

If there are Changes, check if the item that you think that should be updated is changed:

```
IEnumerable <DbEntityEntry<Cl>> entries = dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries<Cl>;

// We're expecting exactly one entry:
DbEntityEntry<Cl> myEntry = entries.SingleOrDefault();
Assert(myEntry != null);
```

If null, try to find out why it is not tracked. Was it tracked after you fetched it, before you changed it? Do you have somewhere tracking switched off? Write some other debug code where you fetch some other data. Is that tracked?

If not null, then apparently your Cl is tracked. It ought to be changed:

```
Assert(myEntry.State == EntityState.Modified);
```

If not modified, fetch the original values and the current values:

```
DbPropertyValues originalValues = myEntry.OriginalValues;
DbPropertyValues currentValues = myEntry.currentValues;
```

In your debugger, check them, or write some debug code to compare the original value with the current values. Are the changed values correct?

I'm not sure if entity framework will try to update objects that are unmodified and of which the original values are not equal to the current values. We'll find out to see what SQL is created when you do the SaveChanges.

It would be nice if your database can log all communications.

You can also log what entity framework sends to your database. For this, use property [DbContext.Database.Log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/logging-and-interception). For example:

```
dbContext.Database.Log = Console.Write;
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

If you can't write to Console, write a method:

```
private List<string> SqlCommands {get;} = new List<string>();

void LogSqlCommands(string sqlCommand)
{
    this.SqlCommands.Add(sqlCommand);
}
```

And in your method that following debug code:

```
using (var dbcontext = new EVEntities())
{
    this.SqlCommands.Clear();
    dbContext.Database.Log = this.LogSqlCommands;
    var data_header = ... etc

    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Put a breakpoint after SaveChanges and check the generated SQL.

Hope these debugging tips help you to find the cause of your problem

Comment: `HasChanges()` is a method, not a property.

Comment: So what kept you from correcting my answer?